# fill form of popup or prompted window in pyppeteer python

Tags: python, python-3.x, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, pyppeteer

I am using pyppeteer in python to do some automation.Everything was fine until i got one form in popup
window which i am trying to fill,  i am not able to take control of that popup/prompted form.
I tried to get control of this popup by using pages() function but not able to get control and Can
someone please check this issue.I am new to pyppeteer.

```
await page.click("#popuplink_id")
pages = await browser.pages()
popup = pages[len(pages) - 1]
await popup.bringToFront()
await page.waitForSelector('#popup_text_box_id', { 'visible': 'true' })
await popup.type('#popup_text_box_id','value')
```

Comment: Please provide a small script we can test with. Thanks.

Comment: Is the popup opening in the new tab? The method `browser.pages()` resolves an array of all open pages/tabs, not the popups. I believe the popup appears on the same page, so you can use just the `page.waitForSelector`